# OpenVPN Not Forwarding Traffic on Ethernet

Tags: networking, openvpn

For some reason, my OpenVPN connection does not connect to the internet when I connect to the server over a wired connection. This seems to only be happening on Ubuntu 15.10, as I can connect out on my other laptop running 14.04 when connected to wired.

When I am on wireless, I can connect to the OpenVPN server I run at home, and then my client connects out to the internet just fine. I can access all VPN network resources and shares, and I can connect to sites such as Google.

However, when I connect to OpenVPN via wired, it fails all attempts at hostname resolution. I can ping out to `74.125.51.245` and `8.8.8.8`, but trying to ping or traceroute to `www.google.com`, I get `Name not Resolved` errors. VPN network resources such as shares and web-interfaces work fine, still.

Comment: whats your /etc/network/interfaces?